# Usecase for BIgQuery as a database backend for website thoughts

Tags: sql, database-design, google-bigquery

members,

Currently we synchronise salesdata into BigQuery, and it allows us to make fast, detailed, practically realtime reports of all kinds of stats that we otherwise would not have available. We want to have a website that is able to use these reports and present this information to website-users.
Some specs:

- Users are using the data as 'readonly'
- We want to do the analysis 'on request', so as soon as a user opens the page, we would query BigQuery and the user would see their stats depending on the query
- The stats could change for external sources but often the result will be equal, I take into my mind that BigQuery would cache the query
- The average query processes about 100Mb of data, it takes >2 seconds for the whole backend to respond (so user request, query, return resultset)  so performance is what we want

Why I doubt:

- BigQuery would not be adviced
- Could it run 'out of hand'
- Dataset will grow bigger, but we will need to keep using all historical data in any case

I would be an option to get aggregated data into another database for doing the main calls, but that would give me not a 'realtime' experience.

I would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by “out of hand”?  And also what is your  expected volume of data?

Comment: I have about 500000 lines that need to be aggregated on roughly 4000 accounts, with some joins of smaller tables. The buildup will be linear over time, so grow with about 200000 lines per year.

Comment: You can consider BigQuery as an option since BigQuery is fully managed and supports analytics over petabyte-scale data and specially designed for performing OLAP transactions so analysis can be performed on requests. Use caching to  query and fetch results quickly. For large datasets,create [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) to store and manage data. For accessing historical data, expiration time of the table can be set and you can check the [optimized storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage) for your requirement.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, you can consider Bigquery as an option since Bigquery is fully managed and supports analytics over petabyte-scale data, it will be able to handle large amounts of data. Bigquery is specially designed for performing OLAP transactions so analysis can be performed on requests. Bigquery uses cached query results through which you can cache the query and fetch results quickly.

If your dataset is very large and grows  then you can create  [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) to store and manage your data and easily query the tables. Since your data can go out of hand, Bigquery being a fully managed service will automatically handle that load. Historical data can be stored and accessed but for that you can set the expiration time of the table and also check the [optimized storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage) according to your requirement.